# Как копировать файл из ресурсов в память телефона/эмулятора?

Tags: android, память, resources, filestream

В папку res/raw добавил файл таблицы name.csv

Нужно скопировать этот файл из ресурсов в память телефона/эмулятора. Как это сделать?

Comment: Пока что думаю открыть прочитать и записать в другой файл, но как то это неправильно и излишне

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал как то так:

```
Activity resourceProvider;
private String fileName = "sprayballs.csv";
InputStream sourceFile;
File destFile;

public Sprayballs(Activity activity) {
    this.resourceProvider = activity;
    this.sourceFile = resourceProvider.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sprayballs);
    this.destFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        try {
            this.copyCSV();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void copyCSV() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sourceFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            sourceFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
            fos.write(builder.toString().getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```